# how can i send to server without image in volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

this is my method to post in server with two string and one image here i van send data correctly but when i send without image no data can be sent i want to send string and image in all cases with image and without image.

```css
  private void Posts()
    {

        final StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uploadeImageUrl,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

                            String Response=jsonObject.getString("response");
                            Toast.makeText(Post.this,Response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            imagepost.setImageResource(0);
                            imagepost.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String,String> params =new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name",editwriter.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("postcontent",editsubject.getText().toString().trim());

                params.put("imagepost",imageToString(bitmap).trim());

                return params;
            }
        };

        Mysingletone.getInstance(Post.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
    }
```

this is the code of imagetostring with method that get image

```css
  private void selectImages(){
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent,IMG_REQUEST);
    }
    private String imageToString(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imgbystes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        return Base64.encodeToString(imgbystes,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==IMG_REQUEST&&resultCode==RESULT_OK&&data!=null) {

            Uri path = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), path);
                imagepost.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imagepost.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}}
```

code of php in server .

```js
$con= mysqli_connect($host_name,$user_name,$user_pass,$dp_name);

if($con)
{
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Muscat");
    $datee= date("Y/m/d");//strip_tags(trim($_POST["date"]));
    $timee= date("h:i:sa");//strip_tags(trim($_POST["time"]));

     $dt=date("Ymd");
     $tm=date("his");

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $postcontent=$_POST['postcontent'];
    $image = $_POST["image"];
    $imagepost= $_POST["imagepost"];
    
    $rnd = rand(0, 5000);
   
    $imgname="imagepost".$dt.$tm.$rnd.".jpg";
       
    $url = "http://devsinai.com/DrSiani/imageUploadPostDr/images/".$imgname;
  
    
 
   $sql="INSERT INTO posts (name,postcontent,imagepost) VALUE ('$name','$postcontent','$url')";
   $sql2="INSERT INTO posts (name,postcontent,imagepost) VALUE ('$name','$postcontent')";
   $uploads_path="images/$imgname";
    

  
 

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
   file_put_contents($uploads_path,base64_decode($imagepost));
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Successfully'));
    
}


else {
 echo json_encode(array('response'=>'fiald'));
}
}  

mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: Please specify your problem correctly. In which case you don't want to send image?

Comment: i want two case with image and without image but i can send just with image if i send with out image no data go to server

Comment: Use if condition to deferntiate between cases such as:

if (imageToString(bitmap) != null){
  params.put("imagepost",imageToString(bitmap).trim());
}

Comment: try with an empty string at the place of image

Comment: same problem i will edit question with php code in server if you can help pls

Comment: What is the error and problem you are facing by adding if condition in  your code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the code of imageToString(Bitmap bitmap)?

**Edit:**
First of all add if statement to getParams() method like this:

```
String imageString = imageToString(bitmap);
if(!imageString.equals("false")){
    params.put("imagepost",imageToString(bitmap).trim());
}
```

and let imageToString method return "false" as String when error.
Edit your php script like this:

```
$con= mysqli_connect($host_name,$user_name,$user_pass,$dp_name);

if($con){
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Muscat");
    $datee= date("Y/m/d");//strip_tags(trim($_POST["date"]));
    $timee= date("h:i:sa");//strip_tags(trim($_POST["time"]));
    $dt=date("Ymd");
    $tm=date("his");
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $postcontent=$_POST['postcontent'];
    if(isset($_POST["image"])){
        $imageChecker = TRUE;
        $imagepost= $_POST["imagepost"];
        $rnd = rand(0, 5000);
        $imgname="imagepost".$dt.$tm.$rnd.".jpg";
        $url = "http://devsinai.com/DrSiani/imageUploadPostDr/images/".$imgname;
        $sql="INSERT INTO posts (name,postcontent,imagepost) VALUE ('$name','$postcontent','$url')";
    } else {
        $imageChecker = FALSE;
        $sql="INSERT INTO posts (name,postcontent) VALUE ('$name','$postcontent')";
    }
    $uploads_path="images/$imgname";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        if($imageChecker)
            file_put_contents($uploads_path,base64_decode($imagepost));
        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'Successfully'));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('response'=>'fiald'));
    }
}  

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: i tried to put comment on it but my account is new and i have no comments, answers or questions. for that reason i wasn't able to write comment @lukkea  when i trying to write a comment a pop-up message told me that i must have 50 REPUTATION to comment.   Thanks for your notice.

Comment: @IbrahimHusin you must change the quality and make it lower (ex. 70). and put if statement to check the bitmap if null return "false". i was edited my answer. hope this will help you.